# Image manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, image-manipulation

I want to copy an image with all its parameters, including the manipulation data (scale, rotatio etc).
I'm creating a new image control and copy the source and size but can't find a way to set the same manipulation data.

I'm using System.Windows.Controls.Image and i have the ManipulationData object of the source image.

Have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's very good nuget package available for this..

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22Magick.NET%22

For example to crop or resize an image:

```
MagickImage image = new MagickImage("filepath.jpg");
image.Crop(new MagickGeometry(424, 448, 224, 224));
image.Resize(123,234);
image.Write("output.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RenderTargetBitmap` to render any UIElement to bitmap:

The class exists in both, WPF and Windows Store Apps, however the usage is slightly different.

WPF Links:
 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Windows Store Links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298548
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20648.using-the-rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-store-apps-with-xaml-and-c.aspx#Use_its_Pixels